# Applying Noether's Theorem for a Relativistic Point Particle

Tags: special-relativity, lagrangian-formalism, energy-conservation, mass-energy, noethers-theorem

Let us consider a relativistic point particle action
$$ \begin{equation} S= -mc\int \sqrt{-\frac{dz^\mu}{d\sigma}\frac{dz_\mu}{d\sigma}} d\sigma \end{equation} $$ for some arbitrary curve parameter $\sigma$ and we use the mostly plus metric. My aim is to find the total energy through Noether's theorem by considering $\delta z^\mu$ translations restricted to the symmetry variation : $\delta z^0 = c\epsilon~,\delta z^i=0$. The calculation consists of three parts : 1) Find the total boundary term in the variation of the action, and 2) Find how the Lagrangian transforms under the symmetry variation. 3) Construct the Noether charge. So we have :

1. **Total variation :** $$ \begin{equation} \delta S = -mc \int d\sigma \frac{d}{d\sigma} \left[\frac{z^\mu}{\sqrt{-\dot{z}_\mu\dot{z}^\mu}}\right] \delta z_\mu \end{equation} $$ and this brings the boundary term $$\begin{equation} Q= -\epsilon \frac{mc^3}{\sqrt{-\dot{z}^\mu\dot{z}_\mu}}=-\epsilon \frac{mc^2}{\sqrt{1-\frac{\dot{z}_i^2}{c^2}}}=-\epsilon( \gamma mc^2) \end{equation} $$
2. **Lagrangian variation** : Lagrangian is $$L=-mc\sqrt{-\dot{z}^\mu\dot{z}_\mu}$$ which brings
   $$ \begin{equation} \delta L = \frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{z}^\mu}\delta{\dot{z}^\mu}= mc \frac{\dot{z}^\mu \ddot{z}_\mu}{\sqrt{-\dot{z}^\mu\dot{z}_\mu}}\epsilon = \epsilon \frac{d}{d\sigma}L \end{equation} $$ where we used $$\delta \dot{z}^\mu = \epsilon\ddot{z}^\mu$$ and hence the boundary term
   $$ \begin{equation} K= \epsilon L \end{equation} $$
3. **Noether charge :** $$ \begin{equation} E= K-Q = -mc^2\sqrt{1-\dot{z}_i^2/c^2} + mc^2\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\dot{z}_i^2/c^2}} = \frac{m\dot{z}_i^2}{\sqrt{1-\dot{z}_i^2/c^2}} = \gamma m \dot{z}_i^2\end{equation} $$

Physically, I would expect that the Noether should be equal to total relativistic energy $$ \begin{equation} E=\gamma mc^2 \end{equation} $$  but not $ \gamma m \dot{z}_i^2 $ which seems as a non-sense quantity to me. So, what's going wrong in the above calculation ?

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, here is a straightforward derivation:

1. The 4-position $x^{\mu}$ is a [cyclic variable](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Cyclic_coordinates) for the Lagrangian for massive relativistic point particle is$^1$
   $$\begin{align} L_0~=~&-m_0c\sqrt{-\dot{x}^2}, \cr \dot{x}^2~:=&~\dot{x}^{\mu}\eta_{\mu\nu}\dot{x}^{\nu}, \cr \dot{x}^{\mu}~:=~&\frac{dx^{\mu}}{d\lambda}.\end{align}\tag{1}$$
2. [Noether's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noether%27s_theorem) then yields that the corresponding Noether charge is the 4-momentum
   $$ p_{\mu}~=~\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{x}^{\mu}}~=~\frac{m_0c\dot{x}_{\mu}}{\sqrt{-\dot{x}^2}}.\tag{2}$$
3. In the static gauge $\lambda=t=\frac{x^0}{c}$, eq. (2) is the standard expression for the [4-momentum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four-momentum). In particular the 0-component (times $c$)
   $$p^0c~=~m_0\gamma c^2\tag{3}$$
   is the total energy, cf. OP's question.

--

$^1$ We use the sign convention $(-,+,+,+)$ for the Minkowski metric  $\eta_{\mu\nu}$.